# Is there analog of aticonfig --set-powerstate for open source radeon driver?

Tags: ubuntu, graphics-card, power-management, ati-mobility-radeon, fglrx

I'm running Ubuntu 9.04 on relatively old laptop with ATI Mobility x600 inside. On the last version of Ubuntu, when I was able to run proprietary fglrx driver, I was able to slow down graphic card by `aticonfig --set-powerstate 1` and save some battery charge. Now I forced to run open source driver as ATI decided to drop support for old cards. But I can't find a way to control power states now except relying on DynamicClocks option in xorg.conf.

But I really know better when and what powerstate I want, so is there a tool that let me change power state manually or at least let me somehow change the behavior of automatic power state selection?

Answer (score 1):

check the directory

/sys/class/drm/card0/power

it has several files that modify the cards power, most will have to first have the module, "radeon",  loaded with dynclks=1

should be able to echo "high", "mid", "low", or "auto" into the control file and change the clock speed